# Specify form designated for login?

Tags: html

Is there an attribute or some way to designate a form as a login form so the browser knows to prompt to save username/password?

To be clear:

I'm looking for something on the client side to specify what a `<form>` tag or perhaps `<input>`s within are going to be used for.

I want to do this so that if I have multiple forms on one page, the browser knows which one is designated as a login form and will prompt to save a username / password combo when it's submitted.

Comment: No. You have to create your login form yourself.

Comment: WOW DID ANY OF YOU EVEN READ MY QUESTION?? I'm not asking how to make a login form, I'm asking how to DESIGNATE a <form> tag as a login form so the browser knows. READ QUESTIONS BEFORE YOU DOWNVOTE.

Comment: IF it isn't possible that's fine! But it doesn't make it a bad question!

Comment: Only if you're using some kind of third-party framework. You'd need to write script to do this on your own. I'd really recommend you use a server-side technology to do this. All you can really do client side is flag the password box as type=password, which would mask it from the user and discourage shoulder surfing. Key word here is discourage.

Comment: @saricDen Yelling at people isn't going to help at all. I didn't downvote this, but some reasons I can think of why people might downvote this question are: 1) Your question could be more specific as to what exactly you want, and 2) This question is something you could do some research on your own for (such as read up on html forms, or html login pages). Those are just my guesses as to why people downvoted you.

Comment: I did research beforehand. I'm angry because I don't see how it was unclear in the first place. I've specified further, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

Do you mean **htaccess password protection** ?  If so, put an .htaccess file in the directory you want to protect.

reading your last note, there is not a special tag to declare a form as login form.